# How to add control variable in regression using sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I am trying to perform controlled regression using sklearn, I have been using sklearn for fitting dependent variable and independent variable, however, if there is a variable that I want to control for while fitting how do I do that in Python? Here is R implementation for the same.

```
fit <- lm(Y ~ X + C, data = ...)
summary(fit)
```

where Y is the dependent variable, X is the independent variable and C is the control variable.

Comment: You add it to the data frame of predictors and go. However, if you're "controlling" for some other variable, this sounds more like a problem in statistical inference (something like ANCOVA) than machine learning, in which case, statsmodels is the library that gives parameter inference.